# How to get an object's value from another object's key?

Tags: javascript

Having:

```
const colors = [
  {id: 1, name: "blue"},
  {id: 2, name: "red"},
  {id: 3, name: "green"}
];
```

And:

```
const shirts = [
  {id: 1, color: 2},
  {id: 2, color: 3},
  {id: 3, color: 2},
  {id: 4, color: 1},
  {id: 5, color: 3}
];
```

How can I reference the colors in `shirts` by the `id` in colors? I need to end up with `shirt.color = blue`.

I'm thinking about something like this, but can't get it right:

```
if (shirt.color === color.id) {
   shirt.color = color.name;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add what you have tried so far ? also the desired output

Comment: Bad data design makes it more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: Colors should be an object not an array. That would make it trivial.

Comment: I've included that: I need to end up with `shirt.color = blue`, and I'm trying to do something sort of ```if (shirt.color === color.id) {
   shirt.color = color.name;
}```but I'm stuck.

Comment: If by itself makes no sense, are you looping??

Comment: @LewisLlobera please post the code you've written so far, so that will help you understand and also the answerer can explain you where you're going wrong

Comment: @epascarello true that, but I can't change it.

Comment: The thing is: I don't know how to approach it. My basic idea is to loop over `shirts` to check if the color is in `colors` and reassign its value.

Comment: @LewisLlobera you should try to write down your basic idea in code, that will help you learn, anyways there are already lots of answer below you can see how to approach it, have a good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forEach

```js
    const colors = [
      {id: 1, name: "blue"},
      {id: 2, name: "red"},
      {id: 3, name: "green"}
    ];

    const shirts = [
      {id: 1, color: 2},
      {id: 2, color: 3},
      {id: 3, color: 2},
      {id: 4, color: 1},
      {id: 5, color: 3}
    ];

   
shirts.forEach(e=>{
  colors.forEach(c=>{
    if(e.color == c.id ){
      e.color = c.name;
    }
  })
})

    console.log(shirts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` for that to loop over the `colors` and then use `Array.filter()` to get all the shirts that matches `color.id === shirt.color`. With that you can then assign that color name to all the shirt object as expected.

```js
const colors = [
  {id: 1, name: "blue"},
  {id: 2, name: "red"},
  {id: 3, name: "green"}
];

const shirts = [
  {id: 1, color: 2},
  {id: 2, color: 3},
  {id: 3, color: 2},
  {id: 4, color: 1},
  {id: 5, color: 3}
];

colors.map((color) => {
  let matchShirt = shirts.filter((shirt) => color.id === shirt.color);
  matchShirt.forEach((shirt) => shirt.color = color.name);
});
console.log(shirts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and create new objects with the color name.

```js
const
    colors = [{ id: 1, name: "blue" }, { id: 2, name: "red" }, { id: 3, name: "green" }],
    shirts = [{ id: 1, color: 2 }, { id: 2, color: 3 }, { id: 3, color: 2 }, { id: 4, color: 1 }, { id: 5, color: 3 }],
    colorMap = new Map(colors.map(({ id, name }) => [id, name])),
    result = shirts.map(o => ({ ...o, name: colorMap.get(o.color) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: the Map has a faster access with O(1).

Comment: An object is simpler and also O(1).

Comment: @NinaScholz `Map` has `O(1)` access not `O(n)`, isn't it ?

Comment: @CodeManiac, sorry. typo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const colors = [
  {id: 1, name: "blue"},
  {id: 2, name: "red"},
  {id: 3, name: "green"}
];

const shirts = [
  {id: 1, color: 2},
  {id: 2, color: 3},
  {id: 3, color: 2},
  {id: 4, color: 1},
  {id: 5, color: 3}
];

shirts.forEach(s => {
 s.color = (colors.find(c => c.id === s.color) || {}).name;
});

console.log(shirts);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an object for the color codes, it makes your life so much easier. It avoids having to loop over it and convert it into a format that resembles this for a quick look up.

```js
const colors = {
  1: "blue",
  2: "red",
  3: "green"
}

const shirts = [
  {id: 1, color: 2},
  {id: 2, color: 3},
  {id: 3, color: 2},
  {id: 4, color: 1},
  {id: 5, color: 3}
];

shirts.forEach( shirt => shirt.colorName = colors[shirt.color] )

console.log(shirts)
```

If it really has to be in that format, than do the conversion

```js
const colors = [
  {id: 1, name: "blue"},
  {id: 2, name: "red"},
  {id: 3, name: "green"}
];

const shirts = [
  {id: 1, color: 2},
  {id: 2, color: 3},
  {id: 3, color: 2},
  {id: 4, color: 1},
  {id: 5, color: 3}
];

const colorCodes = colors.reduce((o, c) => { o[c.id] = c.name; return o }, {})
shirts.forEach( shirt => shirt.colorName = colorCodes[shirt.color] )

console.log(shirts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
const colors = [
  {id: 1, name: "blue"},
  {id: 2, name: "red"},
  {id: 3, name: "green"}
];
```

The shape of `colors` above is an array of objects with names and ids. This makes the code needlessly awkward.

We can dramatically simplify things by making `colors` an object.

```
const colors = {
  1: "blue",
  2: "red",
  3: "green"
};

const shirts = [
  {id: 1, color: 2},
  {id: 2, color: 3},
  {id: 3, color: 2},
  {id: 4, color: 1},
  {id: 5, color: 3}
];

function assignShirtColor(shirt) {
  shirt.color = colors[shirt.color];
}
```

Then all we need to do is write

```
shirts.forEach(assignShirtColor);
```